# Loading a helper with express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, helper

I'm trying to load [this helper](https://www.npmjs.org/package/handlebars-form-helpers) on my [Express / Handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) project, but, I can't manage to make it work...

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  helpers: require('handlebars-form-helpers').helpers
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And here is the page when I try to load it

[image]

Kind of new with Handlebars integration with Express, so, I can't manage to figure it out...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
    handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    helpers = require('handlebars-form-helpers').register(handlebars);

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: helpers,
    defaultLayout: 'main'
});

app.engine('.hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

You can find more info here: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/examples/advanced/server.js

Comment: not work TypeError: require(...).register is not a function

Comment: @DungVu check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123988/470707